# PHP return from include file if a function fails

Tags: php, function, return, include

I have `script.php` which calls `include(child.php)`. `child.php` contains a *function*.
Sometimes the *function* fails and produces an error message. If this happens I need to stop running `child.php` and continue execution of `script.php`.
To achieve this I use a variable that is set by the *function*, then is checked outside it and results in return at the `child.php` level.
Maybe there is a more elegant solution, e.g., something analogous to "break 2" exiting from nested loops ?
(I also considered try..catch mechanism)

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Perhaps organising your code into more logical blocks (perhaps OO) rather than entire scripts.